# Are all these ingredients edible?

Tags: herbs, chinese-cuisine

I'm cooking a Chinese soup base kit that I found in my local Asian supermarket (an amazing place!) But I'm not familiar with the ingredients. As some of them look strange and 'woody' I wanted to check if I'm supposed to fish them out like a bay leaf (or rather, strain the soup) or leave them in and eat them? I've checked Google but I'm not sure.

Chinese yam <- pretty sure I can eat this

Fox nuts <- these too

Lotus seed

Changium

Red Medeberry

Longan Pulp

Astragali

Regardless, it smells amazing and has chicken in it too :)

**Edit:** Now that it's been cooking for a couple of hours and things have opened up/softened I'm pretty sure it's all edible. Even the twiggy looking things are now soft and easy to bite into

Comment: [I don't know] but I have visions reminiscent of finding the whole cardamom in the last mouthful of biryani… it's 'traditional' but a roulette in practise. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the medeberry is goji, so that's edible. You can eat lotus seed and Longan pulp. I am familiar with those "packs of dried things" and usually you can eat all of the stuff, but I usually leave the twig-looking stuff.

Comment: Thank you :) yes one of them does look very twiggy...

Comment: Yes, I think you can eat the twig like stuff, too. I just love the dates, goji, and longan flavors more. The tastes are so subtle and nuanced.  Enjoy!